Repair small section of subfloor
I’m attempting a shower remodel and discovered a small section of rotten subfloor along the outside of the shower curb. I’ve carved out the soft (rotten) part and I now have a 2”x6” hole.
Normally I would cut out a bigger piece, add reinforcement, and install the new section. The problem is that there’s tile flooring on one side and a concrete-coated shower floor on the other side. I do NOT want to cut and/or replace tile and I really don’t want to cut out the shower floor.
Would reinforcing the floor with a scrap piece of 2x4 underneath the damaged section and filling with a wood filler be acceptable? I went under the house and there doesn’t seem to be any further damage. Any thoughts or suggestions?
The pic shows the initial damage before I scraped out the rest of the damaged part.


Let's back up and ask ourselves what problem you're trying to solve. What's left unsupported with your plan? Once you wrap the curb and install tile, how much gap is left? How do you intend to finish that area?

The new curb should cover the area even if I did nothing. It still seems structurally sound as is, but I didn’t want to take any chances before installing the pan/waterproofing/tile/etc.
